# Settings Blank On First Launch With registerDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have an issue with registerDefaults of NSUserDefaults with a settings bundle. Perhaps others have dealt with this issue and simply ignored but it's hit a point where I'm convinced this is either a bug or we're approaching the issue incorrectly.

1. Create a new dictionary and register it.
2. Launch the app.
3. Go to iOS Settings App
4. Go to your app settings and see the only things visible are location and camera.

**Previous solution**: *Swipe up on the settings app to close and relaunch it then all of the settings appear.*

Obviously this isn't ideal and although we have been dealing with the issue ever since iOS 7 I believe I am ready for a real solution since it's become more problematic for support lately. Has anyone had this work on first launch and if so, can you please share your technique?

Things we've tried.

1. Moving the register function to init() = same result
2. Calling register after didFinishLaunching = same result
3. Only add one option to narrow down issue = same result

   ```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
       var appDefaults = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
       appDefaults["some_setting"] = true
       appDefaults["some_setting2"] = false
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(appDefaults)
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
       return true
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was **FINALLY** fixed in iOS 10 with no changes necessary to the code above. **THANK YOU APPLE!**